# Predicting from the full posterior distribution using stan_glmer

Tags: predict, rstan, rstanarm

Could I ask for some help please?

I have fit a binomial model using stan_glmer and have picked the model which I think best fits the data. I have used the posterior predict command to compare my observed data to data simulated by the model and it seems very similar.

I now want to predict the probability of an event for different levels of the predictors. I would usually use the predict command in glmer but I know I should use the posterior_predict command for stan_glmer to take into account the full uncertainty in the model. If x1 and x2 are continuous predictors for a binary event and I want a random intercept on group, the model formula would be:

```
      model <- stan_glmer(binary event ~ x1 + x2 +(1 | group), family="binomial"
```

My question is: I want to vary the predictors (x1 and x2) to see how the model predicts the observed data (and the variability in those predictions), maybe as a plot but I’m not sure how. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `posterior_predict` has a `newdata` argument that expects a `data.frame` with values of `x1`, `x2`, and `group`. This argument is similar to that in many other prediction functions and there is an example of using that can be executed via `example(posterior_predict, package = "rstanarm")`.

In your case, it might be something like

`nd <- with(original_data, 
           expand.grid(x1 = seq(from = min(x1), to = max(x1), length.out = 20),
                       x2 = seq(from = min(x2), to = max(x2), length.out = 20),
                       group = levels(group)))
PPD <- posterior_predict(model, newdata = nd)`

but you could choose the values of `x1` and `x2` in various other ways.